# How to show table based on the category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created a table called **jeniskerja** which contains the category (id's range from 1-5) of the **pekerjaan**'s table. I already made the eloquent model for each of the said table;

jeniskerja (model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Jeniskerja extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function pekerjaans(){
       return $this->hasMany(Pekerjaan::class);
   }
}
```

pekerjaan (model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Pekerjaan extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = ['tanggal'];

    public function penyedia(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Penyedia::class, 'penyedia_id');
   }

   public function jeniskerja(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Jeniskerja::class, 'jeniskerja_id');
   }

   public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

}
```

At the moment, when the user click on the vendor's name, it will direct them to show a detail of the vendor and the table list of work... **What I need is to show the table based on the category id when the user click on the said category tab... Here is the picture to show the page**
[image]

And here is my code to view the page:

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card card-default color-palette-box">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">
          <b>{{$penyedia->nama}}</b>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h5><i class="fas fa-id-card"></i>&nbsp NPWP: {{$penyedia->npwp}}</h5><br>
          <h5><i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i>&nbsp Alamat: {{$penyedia->alamat}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="solid" style="border-top: 1px solid;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h5><i class="fas fa-building"></i>&nbsp Bentuk Usaha: {{$penyedia->bentuk_usaha}}</h5><br>
          <h5><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp Email: {{$penyedia->email}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>

  <section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      @foreach ($penyedia as $penyedias)
        
      @endforeach
        <div class="row">
          {{-- <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
            <!-- small card -->
            <div class="small-box bg-info">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{$penyedia->count('nama')}}</h3>

                <p>Penyedia</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-store"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="/datapenyedia" class="small-box-footer">
                More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div> --}}
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-8">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-lightblue">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>{{$pekerjaan->count('pekerjaan')}}</h3>

              <p>Pekerjaan</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-map"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="/datapekerjaan" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-8">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-lightblue">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaan->sum('nilai_kontrak'))}}</h3>

              <p>Nilai Kontrak</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="/datapekerjaan" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

@foreach ($jeniskerja as $jeniskerjas)
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card card-default collapsed-card">
      <div class="card-header collapsed-card">
        <h3 class="card-title">
          <b>{{$jeniskerjas->nama_jenis}}</b>
        </h3>
    
        <div class="card-tools">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body table-responsive">
        <table id="tabelpekerjaan" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 10px" rowspan="2">Tahun Anggaran</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Tanggal Kontrak</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Paket Pekerjaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Nama Perusahaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Lokasi Pekerjaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Jenis Pekerjaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">HPS</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Nilai</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Dokumen</th>
              <th colspan="2">Tanggal</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Tgl Buat</td>
              <td>Tgl Update</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @php $no = 1; /*$totalNilai = 0.0;*/ @endphp
            @foreach ($pekerjaan as $pekerjaans)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->tanggal->format('Y')}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->tanggal->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->pekerjaan}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->penyedia->nama}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->lokasi}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->jeniskerja->nama_jenis}}</td>
              <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaans->hps,0,',',',')}}</td>
              @php
              $pekerjaans->nilai_total = $pekerjaans->nilai_1 + $pekerjaans->nilai_2 + $pekerjaans->nilai_3 + $pekerjaans->nilai_4;
              @endphp
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->nilai_total}}</td>
              <td><a href="{{ route('pekerjaans.download', $pekerjaans->id) }}"><u>{{$pekerjaans->status}}</u></a></td>
              <td>
                 
              </td>
              <td>
                
                
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
@endforeach
```

And here is the AdminController file

```
public function showpenyedia(Penyedia $penyedia){

        $pekerjaan = $penyedia->pekerjaans; //show pekerjaan(work) based on penyedia(vendor)
       

        $jeniskerja = Jeniskerja::all();
        
        return view('admin.showpenyedia', compact('penyedia','pekerjaan','jeniskerja'));
    }
```

Comment: You should use some frontend javascript for this, as it is better than reloading the page with different data

Comment: @Nick So I don't really need to create a database for category and use eloquent?

Comment: no you still will need those, but to do the toggling on the frontend when you click, it would be easiest to use javascript to click the + icon for the area you want to expand